# stopping an applet programmatically from outside

Tags: java, applet, window, exec

I hope I can explain this clearly.  I want to stop an applet, programmatically, from outside, in a `polite' manner that still returns a status code 0.

More detail:  I'm working on a testing/benchmarking framework that exec()s "appletviewer embed.html" and gets the pid of the process thus launched.  What I've been doing then is waiting for five seconds, then opening the X display and searching for a window whose **_NET_WM_PID** property equals the pid, and sending **WM_DELETE_MESSAGE** to that window.  However, this only works for Java 1.5 and above because 1.4 and below do not set **_NET_WM_PID** so I can't find the window that's just been opened.

Just to be clear:  using *signal()* isn't what I want because the closure of the applet should be `normal', i.e. should not make appletviewer return non-zero.

Just to be clear again:  this is a testing/benchmarking framework;  the stopping must be initiated by the framework and not by modifying the applet.  We have a lot of applets to test/run and the framework must run them all, one by one, without user interaction.

Methods I've considered are:

1. Make a list of windows whose **WM_CLASS** property includes **sun-applet-main**, before
   and after the *exec()*, and diff the lists to work out what windows
   opened after the *exec()*.
2. Write my own appletviewer and make it
   accept **SIGUSR1** and close the applet, e.g., by calling the
   *destroy()* method.

Any better suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The *-debug* option to appletviewer provides an answer:

```
 (echo run;sleep 5;echo exit) | appletviewer -debug embed.html
```

I'll be doing that in the benchmarking framework but the shell-command form above shows the idea more clearly.

Correction to the original question:  the _NET_WM_PID property is set by appletviewer in Java 1.7 and later.  It is not set by 1.6 and earlier.